# PHP only allow full path with is_file

Tags: php

I want to find if a file exists but only if the full file path if provided.

```
$file = "C://dir/dir/file.txt"; // should return true

$file = "file.txt" //should return false;
```

Both files exist, in fact they are the same file.

```
function is_absolute_file($file){

    return is_file($file) && strpos($file, ":". DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR) === 1 ;
}
```

Although this does work I would have to do a `str_replace` on all slashed to make sure they match `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.

There must be a better way. any ideas ?

Comment: `realpath(file) == file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`realpath()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) to generate the absolute path and then compare it.

```
function is_absolute_path( $path ) {
  return ( $path == realpath( $path ) );
}
```

If the provided path already is an absolute path it should be identical to the path generated by `realpath()`.

Comment: Perfect, Thanks, i will accept as soon as it lets me